# Sqllite database doesnt copy in the sd card in real device

Tags: java, android

I am copying my database(sqllite) to sd card by this method:

```
String currentDBPath =
                "\\data\\com.powergroupbd.tripmileage\\databases\\tripmileagedatabase";
                 String backupDBPath = "tripmileagedatabase";
                File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBpath);
                File backupDB = new File(sd, BackupDbPath);

                if (currentDB.exists()) {
                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB)
                            .getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB)
                            .getChannel();
                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    src.close();
                    dst.close();
```

This is working fine in emulator but when I install it in real device this doesnt show any file in sd card. What I am missing?

Comment: No, it doesnt show any thing :(

Comment: I just cant find the file in sd card in mnt/sdcard/ path but in emulator it does show

Comment: Are you sure that currentDB.exists() returns true on the real device? As far as I know, there is no guarantee that the data directory starts with /data/.. Also, did you try using / instead of \\ as a separator?

Comment: I am sure that it returns true everytime. But I didnt use / as seperator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to the database starts from /data/data/. Notice the path separator is forward slash, instead of back slash. So change your code to:

```
String currentDBPath =
            "/data/data/com.powergroupbd.tripmileage/databases/tripmileagedatabase";
             String backupDBPath = "tripmileagedatabase";
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBpath);
            File backupDB = new File(sd, BackupDbPath);

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB)
                        .getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB)
                        .getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
```

Comment: This one worked but my previous one was working in emulator though